# AttributeError " 'Call' object has no attribute 'starargs' in CherryPy with Python 3.5

Tags: cherrypy, python-3.5

Short version: 
CherryPy seems to break when run under python 3.5. Minimal working example below.

Long version: 
I'm using CherryPy to serve a web-based GUI for a little tool I made with a friend. When Python 3.5 was released and I tried running our project with it, it broke. That obviously shouldn't happen. 
Now, I've finally had time to investigate and build a minimal working (well, broken) example of the error. 
The offending line seems to be in server.conf, Line 10.

server.py

```
import cherrypy


class WebServer(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'This is the index!'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cherrypy.config.update('server.conf')
    cherrypy.quickstart(WebServer(), '/', 'server.conf')
```

server.conf

```
[global]
server.socket_host: "0.0.0.0"
server.socket_port: 8080

[/]
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.sessions.timeout = 60
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "static"
tools.staticdir.root = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

Static contains this HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>If you can read this, the code works.</title>
</head>
<body>
Plain HTML.
</body>
</html>
```

Running server.py with Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 15.10 results in the following error:

```
ValueError: ("Config error in section: '/', option: 'tools.staticdir.root', value: 'os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())'. Config values must be valid Python.", 'AttributeError', ("'Call' object has no attribute 'starargs'",))
```

For some reason, under Python 3.4.3, os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) is perfectly valid, but not under Python 3.5...

Can anyone help me out, here?

Comment: If there's a bug in CherryPy, you should raise it with the package maintainers.

Comment: I don't yet know if it's a bug in CherryPy or me doing something unpythonic...

Comment: Could you give an actual [mcve] then; one that runs, with a full traceback.

Comment: Is it better now? I added the HTML file and the error message. I think that was all that was missing. Oh, and I specified my OS, just in case...

Comment: The indentation in your code is still off.

Comment: Thanks. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: ...what is `application-specific.` supposed to be doing?

Comment: I saw this on the cherrypy issue tracker if you have not seen it yet.